# What is the difference between user/kernel mode and protected/real mode? Are they the same?

Tags: kernel, protected, mode

After I read about these concepts, it seems that both user/kernel modes and real/protected modes were intended for protection purposes. Basically these modes are differentiated to prevent crash of one program by another. So why use different terms for one and the same thing?

Answer (score 8):

These terms are different. Moreover, both *user* and *kernel* OS modes are related to *protected* processor's mode.

**User mode** and **kernel mode** are modes of the **process** from the view of the operating system. Same process can **switch** modes **many times** during system uptime.

**Real mode** and **protected mode** are modes of the **processor** (usually these modes refer to x86 family). **Switch** from real to protected mode is performed **once** during system startup. All futher instructions are executed in *protected* mode. (I am not sure, whether additional switch to real mode is perfomed on system shutdown.)